# Angular JS data is not binding from the view to the model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mddialog

the problem I have is that the text field input from my view is not binding to the controller.

Here's the view snippet:

```
<md-dialog-content ng-if="mode=='addSentence'" class="sticky-container">
    <md-input-container>
        <label for="sentence-text">Enter the sentence to be corrected</label>
        <input ng-model="theSentence" name="sentence-text"/>
    </md-input-container>
    <span flex>{{ error }}</span>
    <md-button class="primary" style="float:right;" aria-label="Save" ng-click="saveNewSentence()">Save</md-button>
</md-dialog-content>
```

And here's the controller function that is supposed to handle the input:

```
function ViewSentenceController($scope, $rootScope, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.mode = mode;
    $scope.user = user;
    $scope.theSentence = null;

    $scope.saveNewSentence = function() {
        console.log($scope.theSentence);
    }

    $scope.cancel = function() { $mdDialog.hide(); }

}
```

When `saveNewSentence()` is invoked it logs `null` to the console, even if I have an input in the textfield.

I'm sure I'm missing something, I can't see it, but I have spent too much time on this simple issue, so thank you in advance for helping out!

Answer (score 2):

Your dialog have is own $scope. So:

```
 <input ng-model="$parent.theSentence" name="sentence-text"/>
    </md-input-container>
```

Comment: I am trying to bind the data within the dialog, not to the parent.

Answer (score 1):

Please set 'preserveScope: true' in Your md-dialog options or.. I'm not sure but try change your ng-model to ex: "dialogObj.theSentence" and read this like this `console.log($scope.dialogObj.theSentence);`

Comment: `preserveScope: true` did not work, and the `dialogObj.theSentence` throws an error: `angular.js:11655 TypeError: Cannot set property 'theSentence' of undefined`

Answer (score 1):

if you could share a js-fiddle of your complete block of code, i could have helped you better. But below is an example in which i have created 2 input fields with null set initially and then i keep updating my ng-model.

```
<body data-ng-app="formApp">
<div data-ng-controller="FormCtrl">
    <p>
        Name of Topic: <input type="text" data-ng-model="formData.title" placeholder="enter a title" />
    </p>
    Subscribers:
    <button data-ng-click="addSubscriber()">Add subscriber</button>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="subscriber in formData.subscribers">
            <td><input type="text" data-ng-model="subscriber.name" placeholder="enter name" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" data-ng-model="subscriber.email" placeholder="enter email" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr style="margin:1em 0;" />
    <p>
        <em>Debug info</em>: {{ formData }}
    </p>
</div>
```

and JS is as shown below.

```
(function() {
var formApp = angular.module("formApp", []);
formApp.controller("FormCtrl", function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.formData.subscribers = [
        { name: null, email: null }
    ];
    $scope.addSubscriber = function() {
        $scope.formData.subscribers.push({ name: null, email: null });
    };
});
})();
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: here's a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cw797a3b/ with the whole Controller, the html, is just absolutely basic mdDialog stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue, in a way, by passing the 'binded' data through as the function's parameter's so instead of letting Angular bind the data from the Textfield I called `saveNewSentence()` with `theSentence` parameters passed to it such as: `saveNewSentence(theSentence)`. It worked. Seems like a cheap trick to me, but:

> if it's stupid and it works, then it ain't stupid

Hope this helps some other baffled soul out there with the similar problem.